# How to change from GNOME to MATE

Tags: debian, gnome, mate

I just installed Debian Testing (Stretch) on my computer, choosing both GNOME and MATE as possible desktop environments during the installation process. The thing is that GNOME shows up by default and I could not find a menu to choose MATE from. I remember using Ubuntu with Unity and KDE and being perfectly able to choose between the two each time I logged in. 
I tried several solutions found on the Internet and they didn't work:

- I don't have a file called "~/.dmrc"
- I don't have a file called "lightdm-set-defaults" in /usr/lib
- My "xsessions" directory contains only "Default Xsession" and "MATE"
- I don't have a file called ".Xclients"; I created it with nothing but "mate-session" written in it, and nothing happened

How do I select MATE?

Comment: Should be as easy as : Log out from Gnome, type your name in the login window, and a menu in the top? is supposed to allow you selecting MATE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well in fact there IS a little icon with a wheel shape but it's not in the top right corner or anywhere in the top, but right next to the log in button; definitely not where i was looking it for.
so question answered!!! hope this is useful for some newbie like myself in the future.
cheers,
maxi.